# error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'stackEmpty'

Tags: c, compiler-errors

This code is for implementing generic stack functionality in C.

```
Code for stack.h
-------------

    typedef struct{
    void *elements;
    int elementSize;
    int logofElementsLength;
    int allocatedLength;

}stack;

bool stackEmpty(const stack *s);
```

### code for implementation in Client.c

```
bool stackEmpty(const stack *s)
{return (s->logLength==0);
}
```

### Error

```
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'stackEmpty'
```

### Comments

The code compiles otherwise and I only get an error on this line. Obviously the error must emanate from this line of code. I am using

> `gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -arch i386 -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP
>   -MF"Client.d" -MT"Client.d" -o"Client.o" "../Client.c"`

to compile.

I am running on MAC Snow Leopard OS. I have imported `stack.h` in my `Client.c` and all other code compiles and runs fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, unlike in C++, **`bool` is not a valid type in C** (unless using `stdbool.h` of course). I've seen `bool` used this way in C:

```
typedef enum { false, true } bool;
```

Comment: Should be `Bool` instead of `bool`! Thu shalt not spell names of people with lowercase letters. Though +1 for the awesome typedef.

Comment: @WTP: Type names should be in lowercase.

Comment: Unless your coding style requires them to be CamelCase (e.g. Apple style.)

Comment: ...or your type is called `FILE` (or `_Bool` or `_Complex` in C99 for that matter).  Tsk, those pesky standards committees!